# Atheros Wifi issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with AR9271 chip

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, atheros, ath9k

Okay I've been troubleshooting this for a couple of hours and I'm not really sure where I'm at but here's the situation and what I've figured out:

I have desktop that I use ethernet with. But in order to connect my phone to it via the kde connect app I need to have them connect through wifi.

I know I have a wifi chip built into this motherboard. It's a weird motherboard that I picked up from a friend, and even on Windows the wifi part of it hasn't always really worked consistently. But after some troubleshooting I've found that despite being built into the motherboard it's detected as some kind of usb device.

The relevant results of lsusb are

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
```

When I look up AR9271 I find a page on debian on how to install to add the nonfree-firmware repo to Debian and then to apt install atheros-firmware. Link here to those instructions: https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc

Trying to add the deb non-free repo to my apt-sources list results in an error in Ubuntu as it's unsigned, and I don't really understand how to get it signed but I did eventually find a package repo that had a port of the non-free repo in a deb which I installed from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/amd64/linux-firmware-nonfree/1.16

But if I then try to apt install atheros-firmware it still can't find the package name etc.

The weird thing is that previous times when I've had it unplugged from the ethernet while installing Ubuntu, it had no trouble finding the wireless and making it work automatically.

This is my mobo btw: https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z77_MPOWER#down-bios

Also I realize that there are many people asking questions already about atheros wifi cards but everything I find seems to be out of date and hasn't worked for me.

Requested outputs:

```
root@lovelace:~# lsmod | grep ath
ath9k                 151552  0
ath9k_htc              77824  0
ath9k_common           36864  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k
ath9k_hw              471040  3 ath9k_htc,ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    28672  4 ath9k_htc,ath9k_hw,ath9k,ath9k_common
mac80211              778240  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k
cfg80211              622592  5 ath9k_htc,mac80211,ath9k,ath,ath9k_common
multipath              16384  0


root@lovelace:~# dmesg | grep ath
[   40.819728] usb 1-1.6: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[   40.819814] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[   41.244513] usb 1-1.6: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
[   41.495377] ath9k_htc 1-1.6:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[   41.758128] ath9k_htc 1-1.6:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[   41.758129] ath9k_htc 1-1.6:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[   41.758131] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[   41.758131] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   41.758132] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   41.758133] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[   41.767477] ath9k_htc 1-1.6:1.0 wlx2016d8371d77: renamed from wlan0
```

And additional ones below:

```
root@lovelace:~# dmesg | grep wlx
[   41.767477] ath9k_htc 1-1.6:1.0 wlx2016d8371d77: renamed from wlan0
[   42.998100] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx2016d8371d77: link is not ready
[   43.143700] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx2016d8371d77: link is not ready
[   43.375675] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx2016d8371d77: link is not ready
root@lovelace:~# rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci1: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
root@lovelace:~#
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lsmod | grep ath` and also: `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: @chili555 Thank you, I've made the edit.

Comment: Looks awesome so far. Now let's see: `dmesg | grep wlx` and also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: @chili555 Sure thing, it's been added.

Comment: I see absolutely nothing wrong; that is, fixable, so far. Does it scan? `sudo iwlist scan` Don't show us all the results, just yes or no and the error if it does not. Is Network Manager running here? Does it show networks if you detach the ethernet?

Comment: When I run iwlist scan it shows a scan of a bunch of networks. Network Manager should be running, I reset it a couple of times today in the process of using stuff. Before and after I unplug it does not show any networks available (though I recognize some of the networks in iwlist scan so maybe I need to reboot to get gnome to show it in the GUI?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81554/discussion-between-chili555-and-david-a-french).